# Restart from scratch the Android app when clicking on the notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that displays notifications.
The app has also different screens, fragments, tabs, submenus....
If the user clicks on the notification the app opens, which is what I want. The problem comes if the user navigates to one of the screens or menus and clicks on Home. The app is minimized but it is not in the main fragment. So, if the user clicks on the notification then app opens where it was. What I need is to start from zero, I mean, to start in the Main fragment.
I create the notification using this options:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyMainClass.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Sorry, same results. The app is not restored